# How do I access a member of a struct in an array based on a condition, then work upon that member in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am looking for a specific String within a member of a Struct array, if I find it, I add to a confidence number within the Struct, and if I don't find it, I add it to the Struct. If it's in the Struct but not in the input String, then I take away from the confidence. Perhaps I can explain this better if I go over the use case and workflow:

I am building an optical recognition program on iOS that scans a text for certain key bibliographies, and after it has gained enough confidence that it's picked up all references on the screen the view will transition to a table of bibliographies. The workflow is roughly as such:

1. Run optical recognition (works)
2. Pass OCR output through a regex and build a String array of the identified elements. Let's call it "identifiedReferencesThisLoop" (works)
3. On first pass, it puts the entire OCR output into a Struct array that has two members: the String, and a Confidence level (starts at 5). Let's call this Struct array "identifiedReferences" (works)
4. On following passes, it looks at the OCR output array member by member and sees if it's in the "identifiedReferences" Struct array.

   - If there is a new reference, it puts it into the Struct array (works)
   - If the reference existed, it adds to the Confidence (doesn't work!)
   - If a reference exists in the Struct but is not in identifiedReferencesThisLoop then it takes 0.5 away from Confidence (not implemented!)
   - If a reference ever gets to a Confidence of 0 then it gets removed from the Struct
5. If a certain amount of members of the Struct array have a Confidence that is high enough then the Struct Array gets passed to a Segue which displays the Struct as a table.

The big problem I have is that I can't figure out how to operate on the member of a struct in a loop.

I've tried using whiles and fors and .filter and .map and $0 -- I managed to cross reference the tables to ADD an entry, but I don't know how to penalize an entry for seldom showing up in OCR, or how to add confidence to one that consistently shows up, or how to remove an entry with low confidence.

Struct definition:

```swift
struct referenceIdentified {
    var reference: String?
    var confidence: Int
}
```

In class:

```swift
private var references: [referenceIdentified] = []
```

In private function:

```swift
let referencesThisLoop = OCROutput.regexFunction() // outputs [String]

for index in referencesThisLoop {
    if self.references.filter({ $0.reference == index }).first != nil {
        references.confidence(at: index) += 1 // gives error "Value of type '[referenceIdentified]' has no member 'confidence'"
        print(index + " found")
    } else {
        self.references.append(referenceIdentified(reference: index, confidence: 5))
        print(index + " not found, added.")
    }
}
```

The table comes out good at the end but all confidences are 5 which is pointless and the table ends up having a bunch of invalid entries.

Comment: `if let indexFound = references.firstIndex(where: { $0.reference == index }) { references[indexFound].confidence += 1; print("index + "found")}` ? But naming the var for the loop "index", is misleading, because it's an `String`, not an `Int`.

Comment: What does this line means `references.confidence(at: index) += 1` ? This give you an error because `references` is an array of `referenceIdentified`, as the error says, so it has not the confidence property. Plus, index is a String, so you cannot use it as a real index, because it is not an int. 
Maybe you mean `references[references.firstIndex(of: index)!].confidence += 1 `

Comment: @Andrew21111 With that I get "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'of:', expected 'where:')" and if I switch of to where I get "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(referenceIdentified) throws -> Bool'"

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I forgot that `references` is not `String` type. Try `references[references.firstIndex(where: { $0.reference == index })!].confidence += 1`